# AWS SES very long delivery time

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

Recently via Java Amazon SDK (v. 1.11.202) I queued 1000 SendEmailRequests to the same email address. The requests were queued at a rate of 14/s which is my quota limit. There were no errors. The server was then turned off.

The issue is that the **emails were being received for 3 consecutive days**!

Emails sent via SES should be delivered within a couple of seconds and normally do. I couldn't find any explanation nor information about any queues/timeouts/delays that might be involved on the Amazon side.

- **Is this related to the fact that it was sent to one address?**
- **What can be the reason?**

---

Please don't focus on the fact that it was sent to one email address. It was not intended. I am worried that this could happen when sent to 1000 different addresses, yet I cannot easily verify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be [multiple reasons](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/three-places-where-your-email-could-get-delayed-when-sending-through-ses/) as to why the email got delayed. It is most likely that it was a problem because everything was send to the same email.

> 1. Emails are delayed before arriving at SES The first step
>      in the process is for your application to contact SES to pass it the
>      message. This is one place where problems could occur.
> 2. Emails are delayed inside SES Once SES accepts the message, it will process it as quickly as possible, before handing it over to the
>      ISP. We take latency very seriously, and, in the event of significant
>      service delays, we will update the public status dashboard. SES
>      service delays are, however, not the only reason why emails might not
>      be delivered to the receiving end. For various reasons, the ISP might
>      be temporarily refusing your email. This is referred to as a soft
>      bounce. Typical reasons why ISPs might soft bounce your email are if
>      the destination address has a full inbox, the email is of a larger
>      size than they support, or they have a service issue and cannot accept
>      email. ISPs can also soft bounce emails as a form of throttling – if
>      they see too many emails delivered too quickly they sometimes
>      interpret that as a spammer trying to attack their customers. When a
>      soft bounce event happens, SES continuously retries to deliver your
>      email for 12 hours before giving up. There is no limit of retries
>      during this 12-hour interval, and, as long as the ISP recovers, your
>      email will be delivered. To verify whether soft bouncing is the issue,
>      you can try sending to different ISPs. If you only see delays with one
>      of them, that’s a pretty good indicator that that particular ISP has a
>      problem receiving your email.
> 3. One particularly thorny problem we sometimes encounter is when we successfully deliver the email to an ISP quickly and in the first
>      attempt, only to have it take a very long time to appear in the
>      recipient’s inbox. This can happen for a variety of reasons, for
>      example the ISP is encountering a technical problem, or it is delaying
>      making the email available to its users because it does not yet trust
>      it. To narrow down the problem, try sending to a different ISP (or to
>      a different address in the same ISP), using an email with different
>      content, different (or lack of) attachments, different “From” address,
>      etc. and see if that makes a difference. Remember that as long as you
>      haven’t received a bounce notification from Amazon SES, it means your
>      message is either somewhere in the SES pipeline, with its delivery
>      being continuously retried, or it has already been enqueued by the
>      ISP, and it being processed on their end.

2 and/or 3 are most likely the culprit here. Try to be careful with this tho, bounces can have a very negative impact on your ip reputation and might be a reason for AWS to disable SES for your account.

Comment: The attribution of this post is unclear.  You did embed a link, but this entire post is essentially copy/pasted from the AWS blog.  The copypasta should be a blockquote and the attribution more apparent.